# Shell form in docker-compose file does not invoke command shell?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was always assuming that the service configuration parameter [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) in a docker-compose file is equivalent to the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) in a Dockerfile. But there seems to be a difference regarding *shell form* vs. *exec form*. When using docker-compose, commands given in *shell form* are not run in a shell.

For example, I have this Dockerfile, which is using *shell form*:

```
FROM debian
CMD ping google.de -c 9999999
```

I build and run the image:

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile.shell-ping-debian -t test-image-shell-ping-debian .
$ docker run -ti test-image-shell-ping-debian
```

According to the document, the ping is executed in a shell:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
51344da31794        test-image-shell-ping-debian   "/bin/sh -c 'ping go…"   49 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds                           quirky_bohr
$ docker top 51344da31794
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                21478               21460               0                   10:10               pts/0               00:00:00            /bin/sh -c ping google.de -c 9999999
root                21524               21478               0                   10:10               pts/0               00:00:00            ping google.de -c 9999999
```

Now, I do the same in a docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  shell-service:
    image: debian
    command: ping google.de -c 9999999
```

Again, I build and run:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up
```

But in this case, the ping command is not run in a shell!

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7fdcf4fc27db        debian              "ping google.de -c 9…"   13 minutes ago      Up 6 seconds                            execvsshell_shell-service_1
$ docker top 7fdcf4fc27db
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                22618               22597               0                   10:15               ?                   00:00:00            ping google.de -c 9999999
```

Is this the expected behavior?

I am using Docker 17.12 and Docker-Compose 1.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this the expected behavior because, when you mention  "CMD ping google.de -c 9999999" in Dockerfile, the docker adds /bin/sh -c as a default execution and path for that execution "/bin/sh" which is the first argument in CMD to verify check it in docker inspect command

```
    "Path": "/bin/sh",
    "Args": [
        "-c",
        "ping google.de -c 9999999"
    ],
```

If you add "ping google.de -c 9999999" in docker-compose command, the path for the execution changes to "ping" which is the first argument in the command

```
       "Path": "ping",
    "Args": [
        "google.de",
        "-c",
        "9999999"
    ],
```

The command in docker-compose does not add "/bin/sh -c" as a default execution, because docker-compose is wrapping above the docker image and overrides whole CMD in Dockerfile (which includes "/bin/sh -c" in CMD).